# How to represent a loop in a Class Diagram

Tags: uml

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me how to represent a loop from UML sequence diagram in a Class Diagram.

Here's the Sequence Diagram: 
[image]

and here's the Class Diagram I made from the Sequence Diagram

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

Class diagrams are not about code execution; they are about the structure of your classes. In other words, your sequence diagram has a time component that shows the reader what happens during the execution. Class diagrams, on the other hand, are supposed to show class relationships (i.e. which class is associated/uses/derives from another class).

Comment: That's what I thought but I wasn't sure. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

[UML diagram taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Diagrams_overview) is divided into *Behavoural* and *Structural* diagrams.  A class diagram is *structural*, you would need a *behavioural* diagram to describe loop semantics.

[image: UML diagram types]

UML 2.x sequence diagrams have explicit notation for loops, while loop semantics may also be expressed in activity or state-machine diagrams.

In your sequence diagram, the loop is *inside* the :microndas::iniciar() method/message, and is therefore part of the description of that rather than the class diagram.  You would attach a behavioural diagram to the :microndas class to describe this behaviour is necessary, though your existing sequence diagram may already suffice.

UML is about expressing different "views" or "aspects" of a system,  It is *wrong thinking* to try to express all that is in one diagram type in another - if that were possible we'd only need one diagram type, and I do not want to go back to designing everything with a flow-chart; for one thing the stationary shop no longer sells [those stencils](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mrbill/3267227227/)!